# Equation of curve generated by QuadCurve2D in Java?

Tags: java, swing, equation-solving

I have drawn a quadratic curve using the QuadCurve2d in java using start, end and one control points. Is there a way I can find out the equation of this curve? The reason why I need is that at some point of this curve it might intersect a circle and I want to know their point of intersection. So basically I want to solve two equations, but I dont know the equation of the curve generated by QuadCurve2D.
Any help will be appreicated.

Regards
S

Answer (score 4):

See the Javadoc for `java.awt.geom.PathIterator`, specifically the `SEG_QUADTO` field, in which the control equation in terms of the start, end and control points is given.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Area class. Method

```
public void intersect(Area rhs) {
    curves = new AreaOp.IntOp().calculate(this.curves, rhs.curves);
    invalidateBounds();
}
```

You can investigate the sources to understand how intersection point are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

That function uses a quadratic bezier curve:

[image: quadratic Bezier formula]

You can find it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)